# How to find just the duplicate records across two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to identify duplicate records between two tables.  The duplicate records will have the same playlist name and track id, but will have different playlist ids.  I just need to identify the second of the duplicate record.  So there is a playlist named Music with a track ID of 1.  This is part of playlist ID 1.  There is another playlist named Music that also has a track ID of 1, but this attached playlist ID 8.  I just want to identify the Music, 1, 8 record.

I am able to identify the duplicate records, but am unsure how to pull in the playlist name.  I think I might need to use the EXISTS clause and a MAX aggregate function, but unsure and don't know where to start.  My current code is below.

```
SELECT
    P.Name AS [Playlist Name]
    ,PT.TrackId AS [Track ID]
FROM PlaylistTrack AS [PT]
FULL JOIN Playlist AS [P]
    ON PT.PlaylistId = P.PlaylistId
GROUP BY P.Name, PT.TrackId 
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(P.Name,PT.TrackId)) > 1
ORDER BY P.Name
```

I am trying to get something that looks like the results below.  So for example, Audiobooks with a track ID of NULL appears previously but has a different Playlist ID.  The results should just capture the next playlist name/track ID (i.e. Audiobooks/NULL) match that has a different Playlist ID (i.e. 8).

```
Playlist Name   Playlist ID Track ID
Audiobooks      6           NULL
Movies          7           NULL
Music           8           1
Music           8           2
Music           8           3
Music           8           4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an *aggregate function* to choose which of the values of the duplicated rows you wish to show

```
SELECT
    P.Name AS [Playlist Name]
    ,MAX(P.PlaylistId)   
    ,PT.TrackId AS [Track ID]
FROM PlaylistTrack AS [PT]
FULL JOIN Playlist AS [P]
    ON PT.PlaylistId = P.PlaylistId
GROUP BY P.Name, PT.TrackId 
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(P.Name,PT.TrackId)) > 1
ORDER BY P.Name
```

Note `MAX(P.PlaylistId)` instead of `P.PlaylistId`

For the `NULL` values, try to switch to an `INNER JOIN`

[Here you can find a list of the available functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Great, thanks!  I was able to capture the information I needed.